# Concatenate a dataframe to each row of another dataframe (one to many)

Tags: python, pandas, join, concatenation

so what I am trying to do is:

I have 2 data frames.

```
>>>dates_df
    start       end
0   2021-04-10  2021-04-16
1   2021-04-17  2021-04-23
2   2021-04-24  2021-04-30
```

And

```
>>>product_df
product country
0   12345   US
1   6789    US
2   89012   US
```

What I am trying to do is to get the following output:

```
>>>combined_df
  product   country   start       end
0 12345     US        2021-04-10  2021-04-16
1 12345     US        2021-04-17  2021-04-23
2 12345     US        2021-04-24  2021-04-30
3 6789      US        2021-04-10  2021-04-16
4 6789      US        2021-04-17  2021-04-23
5 6789      US        2021-04-24  2021-04-30
6 89012     US        2021-04-10  2021-04-16
7 89012     US        2021-04-17  2021-04-23
8 89012     US        2021-04-24  2021-04-30
```

To concatenate dates_df to each of the rows in product_df. Is it possible without using any for loop or apply?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add a column 'merge' with a value of 1 to each dataframe and merge on that?

Comment: `product_df.merge(dates_df, how='cross')`